# Microsoft DNS Server: how to configure it to use MSSQL database for DNS data?

Tags: domain-name-system, sql

Is it possible to configure microsoft DNS server (widows server 2008+) to use Microsoft SQL as a data source for DNS data? Is it any guides available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid not. MS DNS only offers two options for back end storage, text based zone files, or Active Directory storage.

What is it you want to gain by storing in SQL?

**Edit:**
AD storage basically means that the DNS data is stored in the Active Directory Database, which is effectively the NTDIS.dit file. If you want to access it, you will need to use LDAP commands to do so. You can get some functionality by using Powershell to access AD stored DNS in Server 2008 and later.

Comment: To use DNS in pair with other application. That other application need to dynamically change DNS configuration data (some kind of dynamic DNS). What is "Active Directory Storage" - is it some kind of database or what?

Comment: Active Directory if where Windows server stores all the domain related information.

Comment: I'd suggest that if your not aware of AD then its probabley not something you want to be trying to learn and experiment with in your application.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of AD, but i'm unsure where it's STORAGE is located and what it's technically ^_^.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I read that wrong, see my update

Answer (score 2):

You could use DNSCMD to change the zone somewhat safely without mucking in AD directly. I say "somewhat" because there be dragons in this land.

If you have your sword and armour, then changing AD can be done with LDIFDE, or directly with ADSI calls.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft DNS isn't what you want to use for something like this. Nor BIND for that matter.

There are lots of good DNS server libraries for many languages out there that support database back-ends. Usually they are focused on geolocation, like [pgeodns](http://geo.bitnames.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else, mucking with AD is not a good idea. If you want your application to interact (add, delete, etc.) with DNS zones\records on a Windows DNS server, use the dnscmd utility.

Answer (score 0):

DNS Server using a SQL backend will just slow up DNS response time. Are you looking to get statistics of the DNS? If so then you need to look at the Windows Server SDK which will allow you to interrogate DNS, of course you will need experience in programming.